# how to print variable in csh which has * in it

Tags: csh

I have a command that returns a string as output consider below code.
I want to assign the output of the commnd to a variable in .cshrc. and eventually to prompt variable.

```
set possible_out = "** NONE **"
set cur_v=possible_out
```

now when in csh if I do

```
echo $cur_V
```

I get output of

[full list of dir][full list of dir] NONE[full list of dir] [full list of dir]

dir = directories in current folder.
How can I print the string as raw string?

Comment: did  you want `set cur_v="$possible_out"`? (note the `$` and dbl-quotes). Also, you will probably need to escape the `*` chars like `\\*` (maybe just one `"\"` char) and depending on the usage, you may need to use as many as 5 '"\"` chars. Consider using a non-shell meta-char instead of `*`. I think `+` won't cause you any trouble in simple cases. Good luck.

Comment: yes I tried to do a sample code here so probably you are right  about $. also escape char  will only be usefull if I am doing it  my self the thing is Possible_out will be a result of a executable command. i.e. `set possible_out = \`cmd_here\` `

Comment: what I learned is instead of printing I cna use the possible_out directly to put in prompt print and can get correct results.